# How to take into account different screen sizes?

Tags: screen, desktop-application, java

I have written a JAVA desktop application using Netbeans IDE, when I run the application it looks perfect on my laptop. However when I installed it on a larger screen laptop, there is some extra space. 
What is the best way to get rid of that? Is there a way I can support multiple screen sizes in my source code or should I create a copy of the project and install netbeans and do the resize at the new computer which defeats the whole purpose?!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Swing, you can use any of the different layout managers.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: I am using the netbeans designer where the layout is null.